# UIView Subclass in Xcode version 5.1

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, xcode5.1

I am looking to create a subclass for my TableViewController but when I go on the menu bar to create new file then a subclass the option to create it is not there.

Can somebody explain to me why this is the case please?

Comment: What??? Can you please provide more information including any code or screenshots to illustrate what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

Should be like this:

[image]

And then this:

[image]

It is surprisingly simple. Make sure you've selected the right section.

Comment: And even if it would be different from your screenshots, it would still be dead easy to start with a plain class and declare it subclassing UIView. Xcode just provides convenient templates here, not less but not more than that.

Comment: @HermannKlecker agreed. But it would be quite hard for a beginner to know what frameworks should be added to `#import` declaration and what should be added as a default `init` method to start with.

Comment: Well, that's documented and not really hard to find. However, your screens should be very helpflul. I did not mean to cricizse them, just adding information.